# Secure connection string in Worker Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, connection-string, azure-worker-roles

What other options are there to secure connection strings and not commit them to version control when using a Worker Role apart from encrypting `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` - if that is even possible?

Web Apps have accessible variables in the portal - that seems not to be the case with Worker Roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Services, part of which Worker role are, do have Settings exposed in the portal and they can be changed just as in App Service WebApps. You cannot encrypt .cscfg on the cloud. You can have them encrypted locally, but you have to decrypt them before you do a deployment.

If you want to secure your connection strings and sensitive data, you could do that by using Azure [KeyVault](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/). Then you can protect your connection strings or other sensitive values and retrieve them from the vault in a secure way within your application.

Comment: Are the Cloud Services settings in the portal not overridden on every deployment, just like the VM size updates?

Comment: If you completely delete the deployment, yes, if it's a rolling upgrade, I think they are not but I'm not 100% sure. It's been some time since I did an upgrade.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true - my Cloud Services do **not** allow you to add/edit settings besides the standard `Diagnostics.ConnectinString` value

Comment: You can override them through the ui but they are overwritten on each deployment